# Why am i getting these errors in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

It works sometime and suddenly I see gray areas in the map on refresh.
[image]

Comment: Are you behind a proxy or your internet failing?

Comment: No internet works fine and no proxy. Google map seems to work fine, it's only leaflet that fails. Not only in my application but also in leaflet map in the leaflet website also shows same console log with gray areas.

Comment: Try accessing http://a.tile.osm.org/0/0/0.png in a web browser in that device, then b.tile, then c.tile. Repeat the procedure in a different computer. Isolate why your device is not resolving DNS queries for a.tile and b.tile but does for c.tile.